# What's the proper way to use CancellationToken?

Tags: cancellationtokensource

I have created a server which executing some tasks with blocking operation, I have used the cancellationToken to stop those task with blocking operation.  The following is a sample task for TcpConnection:

```
private List<CancellationTokenSource> cancellations = new List<CancellationTokenSource>();
:
:
private async Task ListenAsync()
{
    try {
        CancellationTokenSource cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
        cancellations.Add(cancellation);
        TcpClient client = await Task.Run(
               () => listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync(),
               cancellation.Token);
        :
        :
    }
}
```

When I need to stop the server, I will try cancel all cancellation token in the list, then then destory all tasks.

```
foreach (CancellationTokenSource cancellation in cancellations)
{
    cancellation.Cancel();
}

Task.WhenAll(tasks).Wait();  // wait for task complete

: (desotry objects here)
:
```

Unforunately, the Task.WhenAll(tasks).Wait() never returned.  It seems that the tasks cannot be stopped.  But if I add some debug code in the Try Catch in the Task, and comment out the Task.WhenAll (tasks).Wait(), it will fire the catch statement after cancellation.Cancel(), and the task will be completed.

It seems that if the Wait() is fired in the same thread of cancellation.Cancel(), it cannot release the control to the Task even I have added Thread.sleep() after Cancel.  I need to check Task.wait() in other process (e.g. add a timer to be fired few ms after cancel.)   Or if I do not wait for task cancel, and reset the task list (e.g. tasks = new List();).  Those running tasks will reach the catch block and completed also, but I don't know those resource can be reused after I have removed all reference to those tasks before task complete.

I'd like to know if there has any straight way to wait for task complete using CancellationToken.  So that I can cleanup all objects safety.